# Cannot resolve Property name "url"

Tags: java, spring, swing

I want to run https://github.com/robertforde/Shop in my local PC and
**All property names become red as shown in below picture.** That application uses Swing, Spring DI, JDBC and MySQL.

Here is my error:

[image]